shinyapps.io prevent data loss due to timeout
I am running a Shiny app via shinyapps.io (https://lavaangui.org/). If I leave the browser window open for a while but not in focus, the app "greys out" and shows a "disconnected from server" message. My understanding is that this is the intended behavior, as it helps prevent the consumption of excessive active hours by users who have the app open but are not actively using it. However, in my case, this can result in data loss. I am looking for the best approach to remedy this.
The state I need to save consists of potentially very large .csv and .json files. Ideally, I would like to save the state locally, triggered by the disconnect event.

You can try bookmarking your shiny app as explained here https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/share/bookmarking-state/

You might want to check ?shiny::onSessionEnded()

I also considered bookmarking but since I need to save more than fits in a URL, server sided bookmarking seems to be the only options and "shinyapps.io doesn’t currently supported server side bookmarking" (https://mastering-shiny.org/action-bookmark.html)

Isn't the problem of ?shiny::onSessionEnded that it does not differentiate why a session ended? I only want to save state if the session ended because of the timeout.

@JulianKarch you could set a timer with Sys.time() when the session starts and then check with onSessionEnded() if the session ended after x amount of time.

You could check for inactivity (As shown here) and only trigger the backup once a certain threshold is met.

Great the last comment by @ismirsehregal solves the trigger question. I am still wondering how to best save state. A local file on the server does not work because it's not supported by shinyapps.io. At the same time, I don't want to use remote storage (like Dropbox) because I also want the app to work if it's run locally without internet. Maybe indexeddb?

You could rely on the browsers localStorage. Please see library(shinyStore) or library(shinyStorePlus).

@ismirsehregal, I also thought aobut localStore first, but the state can exceed 10MB, limit is like 50MB.

@JulianKarch sorry for my imprecise earlier comment. library(shinyStorePlus) uses IndexedDB (which you already mentioned).
